# crack a password to uninstall a program

Tags: passwords, uninstall

I installed an app on my computer and when I try to uninstall it it asks me for a 12 digit code to uninstall. I don't remember ever setting up or agreeing to any password.
I tried uninstalling it with an uninstaller but it won't let it. (even forced uninstalling doesn't work.)

How do I crack the password? Where would I be able to get the hash for this specific password?

Comment: Get John the Ripper or such like. There are several. Probability of success is very low. Better approach (and faster) is to back everything up and reinstall your operating system minus the application.

Comment: It sounds like malware... and without knowing the details of the program, it's hard to help you. As @John states, you may need to reinstall everything, and that might not be enough. If you have a disk image without that app, use that instead.

Comment: What application is it? What OS are you using? Have you done a sweep for malware, because this isn't normal behaviour for most applications?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed an app on my computer and when I try to uninstall it it
> asks me for a 12 digit code to uninstall. I don't remember ever
> setting up or agreeing to any password.

This is very difficult to get rid of. Most operating systems today are 64-bit and 64-bit password crackers are not plentiful.

Best suggestion:   Back everything up, make a fresh installation of the operating system, and then reinstall everything but the app in question and also anything you no longer use.

This will be fastest and will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank You! I reinstalled windows and that worked but that got rid of all my apps so I had reinstall all of them again. (a pain in the neck). How do I just reinstall everything but the questionable apps?

Comment: You know what apps you have and so just install your apps and not any others. As you install, you know what you are installing. Just do not install apps you do not understand.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my comment.  What I meant was the windows install has 3 options so at first I tried save everything which didn't help anything obviously, so I did option2 which is save personal files and not apps but I had to reinstall all my apps 1 by 1 afterwards. So I was wondering if there is a way to reinstall windows while saving some of the apps and I would only save the ones I know are not an issue?

Comment: I see. No. The first repair option install ALL software you had, so would not get rid of the one item. The second repair option keeps data but then you install software one by one and do not install the problem software.